# Set $rootScope before textAngular directive initial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I wanna custom [textAngular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) directive options.

The API document says I should set $rootScope.textAngularTools.{customButton} to build a function.

But if I set on controller, directive will tell me property is undefined.

If I set in module.run function, the $rootScope.textAngularTools is undefined.

How do I set the option before directive initialize ?

```
<text-angular to-toolbar="[['customButton']]">
```

Setting like this (coffeescript)

```
$rootScope.textAngularTools.colourRed =
  display: "<button ng-click='action()' ng-class='displayActiveToolClass(active)'><i class='fa fa-square' style='color: red;'></i></button>",
  action: ->
  console.log 'action'
  activeState: ->
    false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from reading the sources i would suggest you do your configuration in a module run function:

```
angular.modul('myApp', ['textAngular'])

.run(function($rootScope){
     $rootScope.textAngularTools = {
         colourRed: {
              display: "<button ng-click='action()' ng-class='displayActiveToolClass(active)'><i class='fa fa-square' style='color: red;'></i></button>",
              action: function(){
                console.log('action);
              }
         }
     };
})

.controller('yourController')...
```

why should this work? They extends an existing textAngularTools object in their directive:

```
$rootScope.textAngularTools != null)? $rootScope.textAngularTools : {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, so $rootScope is prototype for all controller $scope in angular? thank you again :)

Comment: @Chai-YuPai yes it is.